# I have this issue and cant log connect to tor

Tags: error, connection

[image]

The log when i copied:

```
1/30/19, 14:57:17.797 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/30/19, 14:57:17.797 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/30/19, 14:57:17.797 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/30/19, 14:57:17.797 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/30/19, 14:57:17.797 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
1/30/19, 14:57:21.829 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
1/30/19, 14:57:38.765 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host E480D577F58E782A5BC4FA6F49A6650E9389302F at 199.249.223.43:443) 
1/30/19, 14:57:38.765 [WARN] 9 connections have failed: 
1/30/19, 14:57:38.765 [WARN] 6 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
1/30/19, 14:57:38.765 [WARN] 3 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
1/30/19, 14:57:38.774 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/30/19, 14:57:38.774 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/30/19, 14:57:38.774 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Answer (score 0):

This IP address doesn't respond to pings and any connection attempts on TCP port 443. It is either down, firewalled or recommissioned for other purpose (as nmap reports TCP ports 2000 and 5060 as opened and 113 as closed).

Request another bridge address and move there.

Comment: what do you mean another bridge address

Comment: I mean that the bridge you are trying to connect to is down, you have to get another one, for example here: https://bridges.torproject.org/.